# Ordering results of a "distinct" query in QueryDsl

Tags: java, spring, jpa, querydsl

I have an entity with a list of enums. In my query I select all distinct enums from all entities. I would now like to order them by their ordinal value.

My first thought was to use an alias or to select from a subquery, but none of these approaches worked for me.

My query so far:

```java
from(QClass.entity)
    .select(QClass.entity.enumList.any())
    .distinct()
    .fetch();
```

Is there a way to do this in querydsl or do I have to do it in java?